# Change Page / View in iOS

Tags: ios

I have written a function to login to a web service using objective c

```
- (void) registerAck: (NSNotification *) notification {
    NSLog(@"Detected callback for register");
    NSString *status = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"result"];
    if([status rangeOfString:@"Successful"].location != NSNotFound){
      //succesfully registered

      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome"
                                                      message:@"Thank you for registering. Please login using the created details"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

      NSLog(@"%@", status);
}
```

I want to know how I would go about clearing the page and then when the user selects ok on my popup chaining the page to a different one?

The clear page is easy, I would just write a method and then call this before alert[show] but the change of page is where I am stuck - can anyone let me know how I could redirect to a login page  programatically?

Comment: By "chaining the page to a different one", you probably me present a view controller.  Google that phrase and read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html, and you'll be well on your way.

Comment: There's a delegate method in UIAlertView (clickedButtonAtIndex) which you can use, and for changing the view, try using a segue.